# How to get heading only for the main matter in the report class?

Tags: latex

I am writing my thesis in Latex, document class: report. I have got front matter containing of abstract, acknowledgement and so on.

I want to add header only to my main matter which starts with my first chapter:Introduction. I want the header to be the chapter number without the word "chapter" and the chapter title next to it. I also want the page number to appear in the centre on the bottom of the page in all pages of the main matter.

I don't want any header or line in any page of my front matter.

Can you please guide me? Thanks

Here it is the sample code that I am applying.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,titlepage]{report}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colordvi}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{theorem}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage [toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage[left=1.5in,top=2in,right=1in,bottom=2in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\title{xxx}
\author{xxx} 
\date{xxx}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}

\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}

% here it comes my front matter for example:

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\chapter*{Abstract}
ABSTRACT CONTENTS

%then:
\clearpage
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

% here it starts my main matter:
\chapter{Introduction} %first chapter
\chapter{First Esssay in XXX}  %second chapter

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of options to set headers in a document. The most frequently-used package is [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr).

First of all, you need to remove the word `Chapter` from the regular chapter mark. For this, add

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
%\newcommand{\updatechaptermark}{%
\appto\ps@fancy{%
  \patchcmd{\chaptermark}% <cmd>
    {\@chapapp\ }{}% <search><replace>
    {}{}% <success><failure>
}%}
\makeatother
```

to your preamble. The above strips out `\@chapapp\`  (note the space) from `\chaptermark` as part of the call to `\pagestyle{fancy}`. That's required as [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) may update `\chaptermark` upon calling `\pagestyle{fancy}`.

Second, you need to set the headers/footers. Here's a setting that yields what you're after:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancyhead[C]{\leftmark}% Chapter mark
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}% Footer contains the page number
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.4pt}% Header rule width
```

The above sets the header as `\leftmark`, which contains the `\chaptermark` setting (since `\chaptermark` actually issues `\markboth{<leftmark>}{<rightmark>}` with an empty `<rightmark>`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{report} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
%\newcommand{\updatechaptermark}{%
\appto\ps@fancy{%
  \patchcmd{\chaptermark}% <cmd>
    {\@chapapp\ }{}% <search><replace>
    {}{}% <success><failure>
}%}
\makeatother

\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancyhead[C]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.4pt}

\begin{document}

%\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{roman}

\title{xxx}
\author{xxx} 
\date{xxx}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}


% here it comes my front matter for example:
\cleardoublepage
\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}%
\chapter*{Abstract} \lipsum[1]

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\chapter{Introduction} \lipsum[1-50] % first chapter
\chapter{Methodology}  \lipsum[1-50] % second chapter
\chapter{Conclusion}   \lipsum[1-50] % last chapter

\end{document}
```

Note that `\chapter`s are set by default using the `plain` style. If you wish this to be different, you'll have to redefine the `plain` page style.

---

You can achieve the same output using a different header/footer package like [`titleps`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titleps).

Comment: Thank you very much Werner. That's perfectly working!